# php - Facebook post on wall, message containing double quotes

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on Facebook wall, with following code. The message sometimes contains double quotes or other characters which is converted on wall, don't know how to get this resolved. Following is the code I am using

**UPDATE**

```
$title = get_the_title($post->ID); // using wordpress posts' title

//$title = "John's message has \"\" double quotes"; I thought it might be facebook doing something with the title. but by using raw according to Tim, it worked.

                    $attachment = array(
                        'access_token' => $smm_fb_access_token,
                        'message' => $title,
                        'name' => "Site.com",
                        'link' => $handler_url,
                    );

                    $facebook->api(sprintf('/%s/feed', $fb_id), 'POST', $attachment);
```

The post on Facebook becomes like that

```
John&#8217;s message has &#8220;&#8220; double quotes.
```

Please guide what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your code would HTML-escape your `$title` string, so it's getting escaped elsewhere.

The HTML encodings you've given are also 'fancy quotes' and not the ASCII characters in your example `$title` string. (i.e. `“` not `"`) So if something else is escaping it, it's doing it quote deliberately. (like wordpress might cleverly do)

I suggest posting more of your code that shows what's happening to the data on its journey to the Facebook SDK

**UPDATE**

As this is wordpress the `$title` string must be retrieved without HTML escaping. Avoid `get_the_title` which is escaped, and instead get the raw post title with

```
$title = $post->post_title;
// rest of your code.
```

Note that **Wordpress filters will NOT be applied** to this string, which hopefully is what you want. If it is not what you want them you'll have to do as you were doing with `get_the_title` and then HTML **decode** the string. [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) won't help in your case because PHP can't decode the unicode entities. I strongly recommend the former approach regardless.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, what basically I am doing is posting my blog posts from wordpress to facebook wall. so I am getting title as `$title = get_the_title($post->ID);` which sometimes has double quotes etc and it then becomes like I explained in my question.

Comment: thought so. you should have specified Wordpress and that you were doin this. updating answer ....

Comment: Thanks the raw works, I thought facebook was doing something. I tried the `html_entity_decode` but it didn't work

Comment: oh yeh, PHP can't decode `&#8220;` because it's unicode. I'd better add that to my answer too.